# 'zlib1.dll is missing from your computer'

Tags: dll, static-linking

How do I install zlib?

I'm having a major headache trying to get zlib working on my computer. I need it for setting up a SFML [Tiled map loader](http://trederia.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/tiled-map-loader-for-sfml.html), but don't really have a clue what I'm meant to be doing.

I've read the brief documentation that came with the zlib DLL download, and have put the zlib1.dll in my System32 folder, but the test programs that came included with the download keep giving me "The program can't start because zlib1.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." errors.

I think I've set it up right in Visual Studio 2012 as I get no compiling errors, just that error when I try to run the program.

They work fine when I copy the .dll into the same folder as the .exe. Why does what I read about installing zlib tell me to put the dll in System or System32? What is the System32 folder even for?

Will I have to pack the .dll in with any programs that I make? Can zlib be statically linked into my program?

I had a look around before asking but all other questions I found were too specific to be useful for me. D=

Comment: Move it to the c:\windows\syswow64 directory instead.  The system32 directory is meant for 64-bit executables.  Do avoid storing arbitrary files in an operating system directory.  Short from the file system redirector confuzzling you, you are also practically guaranteeing that your program isn't going to work on the user's machine either.  The DLL belongs in the same directory as your EXE.  Add it to your project and set its Copy to Output Directory property to 'Copy if Newer'.